# Problems with Osgi plugins in Domino Designer after 9.01. FP4

Tags: osgi, xpages, domino-designer-eclipse

We have our own OSGI plugin with a set of custom code and some java libraries that we use cross projects. It is installed on servers via an update site and imported on developers Domino Designer.

It is working fine up to FP4, but in Domino Designer it is not added to bundles after FP4. For servers and Notes clients it works fine up to FP6 for which we have tested so far.

Tested now with FP7 on my Domino Designer, and the plugin installs fine both via update site and via manual import. However each time I open a database using this library I get build errors. It solves by going to the code, on the error select correct project configuration and adding our plugin to the required bundles. When I close the database and open again, I have to do the same process and we have the same problem with all databases using this plugin.

I have tested starting Notes with the osgi console, but all reports as it is installed normal there.

When viewing in package explorer before fixing the bundle I can see that the plugin is missing from Plugin dependecies and gets added there when doing the fix.

I just installed a fresh Domino Designer for a new user now and upgraded him directly to FP7. He got exactly the same problem. Downgrading him to FP4 solves the problem.

Anyone having the same problem or have ideas to how it can be solved?

Comment: Strange! I haven't  upgrade to FP7 yet. Can you see anything appear in 'Help -> Support -> Trace' around the time when you open the nsf/project? Usually one of the builders would add the plugin to the dependencies after it discovers the xsplibrary listed in xsp.properties. maybe there is an error at this point?

Comment: Hi, thank you for your input. I got my logging on finest to try to solve this, and regarding this plugin I can see this logging in the trace log:

com.ibm.rcp.toolbox.prov.provider.InstallManifestParser
startElement Feature Added: id="xx.xx.extlib.feature", url="null", match="perfect", version="1.1.35", shared="false", action="install"

com.ibm.rcp.provisioning.internal.impl.ProvisioningServiceImpl
process ENTRY Uid = xx.xx.extlib.feature, version = 1.1.35, name = xx

Comment: I don't know if I can be much more help without having FP7 installed myself! hopefully someone chimes in with a similar experience. other things I would check(forgive me if you have tried already): is your xsplibrary still registered under the extension point (use OSGi console)? do you have any weird version constraints in your manifest.mf? are there any xsplibrary dependencies listed in your xsplibrary Java file that aren't resolving? definitely bundle status is resolved or active or lazy? library is definitely still listed in NSF xsp.properties?

Comment: Thank you for your help again. I have seen trough these items, and cannot find any errors. Strangely the library is listed without any errors in the xsp.library, even before I do the fix to add it to the bundle again. In the clients Osgi console it is listed a Lazy in the Framework list. I guess I will need to register a PMR request.